# Non Resolvable import POM Spring-boot dependencies 2.3.3 Release

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I'e upgraded my spring-boot-starter-parent to the latest version (2.3.3 Release) and since then I can;t build my app. I got an error

```
 Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-bom:pom:1.8.6 in https://jitpack.io was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.3.RELEASE, /home/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom, line 2918, column 19 -> [Help 2]
```

I've already tried deleting whole repository folder and building app from starter, but it didn't help.

I need to upgrade spring-boot to be able to use http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().authenticationManager(authenticationManager());
in my webConfiguration of the APP.

How can I solve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.8.6 is no longer available in the maven central repository.
Please check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-bom

Please check the dependency hierarchy to check from where this version is coming.